# Change directory in powershell script using an XML conf File

Tags: xml, powershell

Im trying to change my working directory in a powershell script using a XML config file.
I have an XML file named "conf.xml" which look like this :

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Config>
    <Paths>
        <pathAW>D:\Workspace</pathAW>
    </Paths>
</Config>
```

---

And I have an powershell script named "test.ps1" which look like this :

---

```
[xml]$ConfigFile = Get-Content "conf.xml"
cd $ConfigFile.Config.Paths.pathAW
```

---

When I want to run this script with a simple command :

```
PS D:\>test.ps1
```

from the powershell command prompt Im getting this error :

```
The argument could not be processed because the value of the "path" argument is Null. Replace the value of the "path" argument with a non-null value.
```

Yet it works when I run the script lines one by one in the powershell command prompt like this :

```
PS D:\>[xml]$ConfigFile = Get-Content "conf.xml"
PS D:\>cd $ConfigFile.Config.Paths.pathAW
PS D:\Workspace>
```

Comment: For debugging purposes, try adding a `Write-Host $ConfigFile.OuterXml` statement in between the two lines in your script, to verify that it's actually reading the right XML file

Comment: The Write-Host $ConfigFile.Paths.pathAW  command doesn't show me anything

Comment: That's not what I suggested :-)

Comment: Yes sorry :) But the Write-Host $ConfigFile.OuterXml doesn't show me anything neither. I think your right : the xml is not read but idk why.

Comment: It's good I found the cause of the problem ! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Seeing this question has been upvoted a couple of times, the nice thing to do is for you to self-answer this, so people can see what the fix is